# Calculate $\mathbb{E}[N(E) e^{-rE}]$ for Compound Poisson $(N(t))_t$ and exponential $E$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, poisson-process

Let $(\xi_i)_i$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables, $(n(t))_t$ a Poisson process (independent of the $\xi_i$) with intensity $\lambda$ and let:
$$
N(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n(t)} \xi_i
$$
be the associated compound Poisson process. Further, let $E$ be an exponentially distributed random variable, independent of $n(t)$ and $\xi_i$. We would now like to calculate the expectations:
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-rE} N(E)]
$$

Comment: Can you calculate $\mathbb{E}(e^{-rt} N(t))$?

Comment: Not really, I would think it's something like the Laplace transform of a compound Poisson process, but I'm not familiar with counting this type of expectations.

Comment: No, it's not the Laplace transform... note that $\mathbb{E}(e^{-rt} N(t)) = e^{-rt} \mathbb{E}(N_t)$, i.e. in order to calculate the expression you just have to calculate the expectation of the compound Poisson process.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! Quite silly of me I was integrating w.r.t. $t$ in my head..

Comment: Do you by any chance also know how to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^E N(t) dt]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Calculate $\mathbb{E}(N_t)$.
2. Since $E$ and $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are independent it holds that $$\mathbb{E}(e^{-rE} N(E)) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{\infty} e^{-rE} N(t) \, d\mathbb{P}_E(t) \right)$$ where $\mathbb{P}_E$ denotes the distribution of $E$. As $E$ is exponentially distributed, say with parameter $\mu>0$, this means that $$\mathbb{E}(e^{-rE} N(E)) = \mu \int_0^{\infty} e^{-rt} \mathbb{E}(N(t)) e^{-\mu t} \, dt.$$ Combining this with step 1, this allows you to calculate $\mathbb{E}(e^{-rE} N(E))$.